# "There were only 4" versus "There was only 4"?

Tags: word-choice, verb-agreement, colloquialisms

I used the sentence "there **was** only 4 channels on tele" (reminiscing about the good old days before digital TV!), but I wasn't sure if I was right, so tried *were* instead of *was*.

It still doesn't feel right, even though I found an article that stated that, as the subject was plural and came after the verb, it should be *were*- but it still doesn't feel right! I've got it in my head that if I had just said *channels* it would be *were*, but as I said "only 4 channels" it should be *was*.

Should I use *were* or *was*?

Comment: Your question appears to be *Does the word 'only' convert a plural object into a singular?* If so, the answer is no. If it's something else, please clarify.

Comment: "There used to be only four channels on TV" eliminates the muddle between was/were and expresses more accurately your meaning. (I remember when there were only three!)

Comment: In fact, long before there *were* 4 channels, there *was* only 1 channel (in the UK), namely the BBC.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I certainly remember when there were only 2; I don't think we had TV when there was only 1!

Comment: I remember when TV *was* in black and white and there *were* no commercials during films!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ditto! There were no commercials at all until ITV came along.

Comment: @TrevorD And what about when we had to turn a handle to make the TV start! :))

Comment: @Mari-LouA You must be older than me - altho' you don't look it from your picture!

Comment: It *was* only a joke!

Answer (score 2):

For some people *there's* has become an invariable word, irrespective of number; but I'm not aware that anybody extends this to *there was*. (I'm not talking about non-standard dialects in which *was* is regularly used for plurals: *we was* etc: that's a different thing).

So, no, I don't think I would regard *there was (only) four channels* as grammatical in standard dialects, with or without the *only*.

Comment: I have heard many Americans (possibly mainly West-Coasters?) use ‘there was’ with a plural subject, so I think the extension to the past tense is quite common in colloquial speech. A regular Google search for “there was two” (with quotes) yields nearly 20 million hits. I would not, however, consider it standard in any form of written English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I suspect that most of those ghits are people whose dialect would allow them to say _we was_, and so not the case I was talking about. But I have no way of knowing whether my suspicion is right or not.

Comment: No, this includes people who otherwise speak fairly neutral, Broadcast American dialects and would always say ‘we are/were’. I also don’t think the number of people who speak such dialects would be big enough to account for 20 million hits on the Internet. There aren’t _that_ many dialects that have _we was_ in any but the most informal of registers. “We was” (with quotes) gives 6.2 million hits (less than one third of what “there was two” gets), despite the fact that ‘we were’ is a much more common and less narrow phrase than ‘there were two’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: OK.